# Creating a N sets of combinations of variables from the given range of each variable

Tags: python, list, simulation, montecarlo

This may be a very vague question -- I apologize in advance.

y is a function of a,b,c,d,e.
a can go from 1 to 130; b from 0.5 to 1; c from 3 to 10; d from 0 to 1; and e is 1-d.

Is there a way in python I can create N (say, 10,000) sets of combinations of a,b,c,d and e from the given range?

Comment: types of `a`&`c` ?

Comment: Look into `itertools`.

Comment: could you provide maybe some example inputs and outputs..

Comment: A lot of questions aren't answered: do you want random combinations or *any* 10000 values? Also, is 1-130 *any* real number or is that an integer domain?

Comment: all numbers are floating numbers. I am looking for random combinations, but I can also use orthogonal sampling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itertools` is a great library for creating iterators like that. In your case, it is `product` that we need. However, you cannot set the number of point you want. You are going to have to derive that mathematically and translate it into steps (the 1s at the end of the `range()` function).

```
a = [i for i in range(1, 131, 1)]
b = [i/10 for i in range(5, 11,1)]
c = [i for i in range(3, 11, 1)]
d = [i/10 for i in range(0, 11, 1)]

from itertools import product

combs = product(a, b, c, d)
for i, x in enumerate(combs, 1):
    x = list(x)
    x.append(1-x[-1])
    print(i, x)  # example print: 52076 [99, 0.8, 9, 0.1, 0.9]
```

The example above produces: 130 * 6 * 8 * 11 = 68640 combinations

These are more than you requested but you get the point. You can also decide to have a variable *more ro less finely discretised*.

I am also assuming `a` & `c` are integer variables..

Comment: `e` depends on the *passed* value of `d`--you shouldn't calculate it beforehand.

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks for that. The fix actually ruins the efficiency since iterator yields tuples which cannot be editted..

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much for your help @Ev.Kounis.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want floating point numbers for all of these.  If you want `int`s use `random.randint`

```
from random import uniform

inputs = [[uniform(1,130), uniform(.5, 1), uniform(3,10), uniform(0,1)] for _ in range(N)]

for input_list in inputs:
    input_list.append(1-input_list[-1])
    a(*input_list)
```